# PubKey SSH Auth fails on CentOS but works on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ssh, centos

I'm going through all of my VMs and adding a nagios user.

When I go through my steps (outlined below) on Ubuntu, things work as expected. However doing the same on CentOS 6.2, I can't ssh via pubkey auth, only password auth.

I've verified that:

- the `/home/nagios` directory has the correct owners and permissions
- the `authorized_keys` file exists and is populated correctly

**What other things should I check?** It is possible that different versions of SSH are causing problems?

### Log when connecting to the CentOS 6.2 remote machine:

```
nagios@redacted:/home/redacted$ ssh -v nagios@remote.machine -i /var/lib/nagios/keys/id_rsa
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to remote.machine [192.168.redacted.redacted] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /var/lib/nagios/keys/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /var/lib/nagios/keys/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug1: Authenticating to remote.machine:22 as 'nagios'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<3072<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:redacted
debug1: Host 'remote.machine' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /var/lib/nagios/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /var/lib/nagios/keys/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

### Details:

Here are the steps that I go through.

1. [Remote Machine] Add a `nagios` user:

   - [Ubuntu] `sudo adduser nagios --system --group --shell /bin/bash`
   - [CentOS] `sudo adduser nagios --system --shell /bin/bash --home /home/nagios`
2. [Remote Machine] `sudo passwd nagios`
3. [Remote Machine] Add the `nagios` user to the list of allowed users in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
4. [Remote Machine] Restart the ssh(d) service.
5. [Nagios Host] `ssh-copy-id -i /var/lib/nagios/keys/id_rsa remote.machine`
6. [Remote Machine] Force nagios to log in only via pubkey by adding this to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

   ```
   Match user nagios
   PasswordAuthentication no
   ```
7. [Remote Machine] Restart the ssh(d) service.
8. [Nagios Host] `ssh -i /var/lib/nagios/keys/id_rsa nagios@remote.machine`

   - on Ubuntu, this all works wonderfully
   - On CentOS (6.2), I can't log in unless I allow password auth for user `nagios`.

Answer (score 0):

A coworker that I asked about this mentioned the `StrictModes` in `sshd_config`.

If `StrictModes` is enabled, the required permissions on CentOS are:

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

[source](http://kb.solarvps.com/centos/how-to-add-your-ssh-public-key-to-centos/)

---

When I was checking permissions on `~/.ssh` and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, I was comparing them against the **Ubuntu / OpenSSH 7.2** requirements rather than the **CentOS / OpenSSH 5.3** requirements.

Ubuntu / OpenSSH 7.2 allow 775 for `~/.ssh` even with `StrictModes` enabled (but still require 600 for `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`).